# Building OCaml stream type without the Stream module

Tags: stream, ocaml

I have to build a Stream type without using the built in module. My code so far is as follows:

```
type stream = int -> int;;
let hd (s : stream) = s 0;;
let tl (s : stream) = (fun i -> s (i + 1));;

let (+:) (s : stream) (c : int) = (fun i -> s i + c);;

let (-|) (s1 : stream) (s2 : stream) = (fun i -> s1 i - s2 i);;

let map (f : int -> int) (s : stream) = (fun i -> f (s i));;
```

However, my attempts to create a simple value to hold a stream so I can test my code have all failed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us your best attempt so far.

Comment: Your stream type looks very strange.  Normally stream is a recursive data structure.  What is your stream's specification?

Comment: `((fun n -> n * 2) +: 4) |> tl |> hd;;` looks like ok.